# What determines your multiversal counterpart?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, loki-2021, spider-man-no-way-home, dr-strange-multiverse-of-madness

Let's say I am a guy Bob in the fictional MCU. So according to the MCU I am on Earth 616 and get transported to say Earth 181(made up), so what will determine my counterpart in that universe?

Simply - Who's Bob in that universe (I understand that there can be many people by the name of Bob but just assume there were only 500 'Bobs' in that universe)

Comment: why is this being downvoted?

Comment: I'm not certain why the downvotes, but I'm not sure that there is a canonical answer to who's Bob's counterpart either, and the writers seem to just make these things up as they go along (by edict of studio executives, presumably). Maybe there *is* a canonical answer about the rules, like: "anything that is possible is certain", physicists would like that. Add: "a lot of impossible things are pretty likely too", and that leaves it open for the writers to do what's necessary for the box-office - I mean story.

Comment: I think the whole point is that there aren't any rules really. _Loki_ demonstrates that backstory, appearance and name don't have to match. They are a you if they are a you and nothing more than that. There might not even be a you in another universe or any other universe (America).

Comment: There are basically an infinite number of different universes, some so similar to each other that they are virtually indistinguishable. The movies simply focus on ones that are as similar or as different from the MCU universe as necessary to tell a good story.

Comment: We saw over half a dozen Loki variants in _Loki_ episode 5, and most of them weren't played by Tom Hiddleston.

Comment: @LogicDictates while in dr strange 2 all of stephens variants looked like him tho we only met 3-4 of them (still dont know why this is being downvoted, i mean its not unanswerable !!)

Comment: I have an issue with this bit: "each film handles the multiverse in their own style. Now here I do want to include movies like Everything Everywhere All At Once but I'll narrow this one down to the MCU". It sounds like you think "the multiverse" is a real thing. It's not. It's just a fictional idea, like a vampire, and as such, the rules are whatever each author decides they are, in a given work.

Comment: Despite the tsunami of two movies and two TV shows (you forgot _What If...?_!), as Stevie-Boy-Weird-Quack says, we know precious little of the multiverse. I think the best we've got is this quote from the Watcher in the Captain Carter episode: "There. That's the moment that created a new universe. When asked to leave the room, Margaret 'Peggy' Carter chose to stay". New universes are somehow created when someone chooses something? As such, whether a being in another universe is considered a variant of you, rather than a separate entity entirely, is probably just a judgment call.

Comment: Presumably Sylvie came about because someone made a decision that eventually somehow meant the frost giant king had a baby daughter, rather than a baby son, who was nevertheless adopted by Odin and named Loki. The two other Peter Parker Spider-Men seem to come from universes with other differences from the MCU beyond their appearance (both have a prominent businessman called Norman Osbourne with a son who becomes a goblin-themed super-villain).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite, I am certainly aware that the multiverse is not a real thing as of now:)

Answer (score 3):

I sincerely doubt there's an in-universe answer to this. I think the whole point of the multiverse is that, in some universes, Bob may look exactly the same but have a different personality. In other universes, he has the same personality but looks completely different. Maybe he doesn't exist in some universes and in others he's basically a god.

I feel like Loki (the show) set this up perfectly well. They clearly demonstrated that, throughout the multiverse, there were plenty of Lokis with a variety of looks, powers, and motivations. What "determined" how each one appeared in their own universe is likely a combination of every alternate choice that existed in that universe leading up to the point that {INSERT CHARACTER HERE} was created/born.